# Why is the "cash credit line" lower than the "total credit line"?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, bank-of-america, cash-advance

In the United States, Bank of America credit cards have both a "total credit line" and a "cash credit line". Why is the "cash credit line" lower than the "total credit line"? (I don't know if that's the case for other/all banks in the United States)

My understanding is that:

- total credit line [=](https://definedterm.com/total_credit_line) ([mirror](http://archive.is/8FGnz)) The total amount of credit available on your credit card account.
  cash advance
- cash credit line [=](https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/credit-card-account-information-faq/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190301013551/https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/credit-card-account-information-faq/)) The cash credit line available is a portion of the total credit available on your credit card, and is the maximum available credit for bank [cash advance](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/what-is-a-cash-advance/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190105161822/https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/what-is-a-cash-advance/))
  transactions. Generally, bank cash advances consist of ATM cash advances, over the counter (OTC) cash advances, same-day online cash advances, overdraft protection cash advances, cash equivalents, and applicable transaction fees.

It's not obvious to me why the "cash credit line" lower than the "total credit line". Maybe cash advances carry more risk for the bank than other types of credit?

Comment: Note that credit cards with the cash advance limit set to $0 are in high demand.

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting. Is it to avoid the risk of misusing the credit card (either from someone else or not trusting oneself)?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks that's indeed an exact duplicate. I was searching for the term "total credit line", that's probably why I missed the other question.

Comment: There are a great many cash-like transactions which are difficult for the cardholder to know whether a cash advance will apply.  Simply disabling cash advances avoids this problem (either the transaction processes as a purchase, or fails, but no fees are charged in either case)  And of course it avoids problems such as loading the wrong card into the ATM.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks that's very good to know.  Do you have an example of a cash-like transaction that is difficult for the cardholder to know whether a cash advance will apply?